# Script to read API with nested array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to bring in an API into Google Sheets. The struggle is I have encountered a nested array within the API and I am stuck as to how to bring it into the sheet.  I have been able to read the ID number but cannot read the rest of the API.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YxGIUTB5AMtufCsc20teVBtUWtmtnPK3WORrz7ybWSA/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7A3SEfxSkEIoslbXrJgVutuAcZqzuok/view?usp=sharing

I've played around with indexes but have not luck.  I can pull the date I want as a query but want to keep it updated without the need for a manual pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your API file and converted to an Object using JSON.  Here is an example of how to drill down into the object and get the arrays.

**Code.gs**

```
function readAPIText () {
  try {
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById("19mTpCSgjNBTlOPofoVrN0KrS5w8tXDhQ");
    let blob = file.getBlob();
    let text = blob.getDataAsString();
    let data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data.length);
    let root = data[0];
    for( key in root ) {
      console.log(key);
    }
    let days = root.AttendanceDays;
    days.forEach( day => {
        console.log("Day: "+day.CalendarDayNumber);
        console.log("-----------------")
        let periods = day.Periods;
        periods.forEach( period => {
            console.log("Period: "+period.Period);
            console.log("Code: "+period.AttendanceCode);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log (partial)**

```
1:19:37 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:19:39 PM  Info    1
1:19:39 PM  Info    PermanentID
1:19:39 PM  Info    SchoolCode
1:19:39 PM  Info    AttendanceDays
1:19:39 PM  Info    Day: 2
1:19:39 PM  Info    -----------------
1:19:39 PM  Info    Period: 1
1:19:39 PM  Info    Code: U
1:19:39 PM  Info    Period: 2
1:19:39 PM  Info    Code: U
1:19:39 PM  Info    Period: 3
1:19:39 PM  Info    Code: L
1:19:39 PM  Info    Day: 4
1:19:39 PM  Info    -----------------
1:19:39 PM  Info    Period: 1
1:19:39 PM  Info    Code: U
1:19:39 PM  Info    Day: 5
1:19:39 PM  Info    -----------------
1:19:39 PM  Info    Period: 1
1:19:39 PM  Info    Code: U
```

**Reference**

- [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)
- [for in](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_forin.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)